# Getting nullspace as clean integers in scipy or numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm calculating the nullspace of a matrix with scipy:

```
from scipy.linalg import null_space

A = np.array([[1,2],[3,6]])

print(null_space(A))
```

This outputs [[-0.89442719] [ 0.4472136 ]], but there is a much cleaner integer solution: [[-2, 1]].  How could I get back a clean integer solution when it exists?

Answer (score 2):

The following approach may help:

```
ns = null_space(A)

ns / np.abs(ns).min()
```

Output:

```
array([[-2.],
       [ 1.]])
```